# Display resolution & Unity: were perfect before restart

Tags: unity, resolution, unity-2d

Today I rebooted my system, after an uptime of 11+ days (suspending once daily) and after an update a few days ago that invlolved fglrx, to see that the screen resolution has changed.

In "Displays" in the settings, the were only two resolution options: 1024x768 and 800x600.

[image]

Moreover, all the launcher icons were larger (I had them smaller than the default using MyUnity). When opening MyUnity I got the following message:

> Your Ubuntu 12.04 is running in 2D mode.
>   Many features will not be available.

I tried rebooting several times with nothing changing. I tried installing mesa-utils as per https://askubuntu.com/a/85322 but nothing changed either.

I finally removed the xorg config file as per https://askubuntu.com/a/407663:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

When I rebooted the resolution was back to normal and the other resolutions reappeared under "Displays".

[image]

The issue that remains is that I am stuck in 2D. How can I go back to normal mode? (And yes I did logout and select "Unity" instead of "Unity 2D")

Moreover, can someone help explain why this occurred?

Technical info: NVIDIA GF119 [GeForce GT 520M], ATI RV730 XT [Mobility Radeon HD 4670, Ubuntu 12.04.4, kernel 3.2.0-58-generic.

Thanks

**Update**
So I searched again and found out the same issue here: [How to change from Unity 2D to 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171853/how-to-change-from-unity-2d-to-3d)

But my case is a laptop; I cannot upgrade my card.

Moreover, It was working normally. what happened I cannot understand. If it helps, here are some more info (lines with "..." indicate repeated lines:

```
    $ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test 
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22

User@home:~$ unity --replace
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x3e00004
....

Initializing composite options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (opengl) - Error: initScreen failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'opengl'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
....

Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'wall' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'wall'
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Initializing grid options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/user/.compiz/session/103b5073b092edf68e139368147689533800000024950007"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'animation' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'animation'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'fade' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'fade'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'unitymtgrabhandles' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'unitymtgrabhandles'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Initializing workarounds options...done
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'scale' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'scale'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'expo' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'expo'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'ezoom' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'ezoom'
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: InitPlugin 'unityshell' failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'unityshell'
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400090!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400099!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
...

compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x840009f!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400096!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
...
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400096!
....

compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
compiz (core) - Warn: unhandled ConfigureNotify on 0x8400093!
compiz (core) - Warn: this should never happen. you should probably file a bug about this.
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing scale options...done
Initializing staticswitcher options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing unityshell options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Starting gtk-window-decorator
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
...

compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
....

compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
...

Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
x^[ Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Choose the default graphicsn in software and updates,additional drivers tab, select: using x.org X server,  then reboot. Once reloaded, go back and select the fglrx (proprietary) and reboot again. This should take care of the issue.

Comment: I can't find that.
Just a reminder that I'm using 12.04.

Comment: There is no drivers in the "additional drivers". There used to be & everything was working well. Moreover the community wiki mentions my chip as for supported https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver